# Copy file name from Text box to another Text box using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two input tags, One is of type="file" another one is text.

When I select the file , the file name by default will appear in the text box whose type is file, but I want it to reflect in another text box as well.

MyCode :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function sync()
{
  var n1 = document.getElementById('n1');
  var n2 = document.getElementById('n2');
  n2.value = n1.value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" name="n1" id="n1" onkeyup="sync()"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="n2" id="n2"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I know why my question is downvoted ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `onchange` and `value`

```js
function sync()
{
  var n1 = document.getElementById('n1');
 
  var n2 = document.getElementById('n2');
  n2.value = n1.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="n1" id="n1" onchange="sync()"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="n2" id="n2"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery` as you've it already on the page(?)

You can use `change` event on `n1`:

```
$('#n1').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        $('#n2').val($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/23rk9nqL/

Comment: @Mitul But he tagged it `jQuery`

Comment: @Mitul, jquery was tagged

Answer (score 1):

I've created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/danbopes/92rw4p8m/). You may also notice that chrome and other browsers like to inject fakepaths as to not give away any information about the source computer. You can strip out the path easily with `n2.value = n1.value.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();` (jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/danbopes/92rw4p8m/1/))

```
<input type="file" name="n1" id="n1" onchange="sync()"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="n2" id="n2"/>
```

```
function sync()
{
  var n1 = document.getElementById('n1');
  var n2 = document.getElementById('n2');
  n2.value = n1.value;
}
```